# C++ Programming Project - Employee Class not outputting right information

Tags: c++

For class I am supposed to design an employee class, and to be completely honest, I have no idea what I am doing. But I do have it to where it prints everything out like it is supposed to, the only problem is it prints the wrong information. I have no idea what I did wrong. If someone could at least point me in the right direction it would be extremely helpful. I tried to go to my schools CS lab and they didn't really help much, I am a beginner and i'm struggling big time.

Here is my Employee.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Employee {
private:
int employeeNumber; // Employee's employee number
string employeeName; //Employee's name
string streetAddress; //Employee's street address
string phoneNumber; //Employee's phone number
double hourlyWage; //Employee's hourly wage
double hoursWorked; //Employee's hours worked
double netPay; //Net pay
double grossPay; //Gross pay
public:

Employee();
Employee(int, string, string, string, double, double);



int getEmployeeNumber();
void setEmployeeNumber(int);

string getEmployeeName();
void setEmployeeName(string);

string getStreetAddress();
void setStreetAddress(string);

string getPhoneNumber();
void setPhoneNumber(string);

double getHourlyWage();
void setHourlyWage(double);

double getHoursWorked();
void setHoursWorked(double);



double calcPay()
{
    const int OVER = 40;
    double federal = 0.2;
    double state = 0.075;
    double timeHalf = 1.5;
    double grossPay;
    double netPay;
    if (getHoursWorked() < OVER)
    {
        grossPay = getHoursWorked() * getHourlyWage();
        netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * federal) - (grossPay - state);
    }

    if (getHoursWorked() >= OVER)
    {
        grossPay = getHoursWorked() * (getHourlyWage() * timeHalf);
        netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * federal) - (grossPay - state);

    }
    return netPay;
}

};
```

And here is my Employee.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Employee.h"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

Employee::Employee()
{
int employeeNumber = 0; // Employee's employee number
string employeeName = ""; //Employee's name
string streetAddress = ""; //Employee's street address
string phoneNumber = ""; //Employee's phone number
double hourlyWage = 0; //Employee's hourly wage
double hoursWorked = 0;

}


Employee::Employee(int empNum, string empName, string streetAddress, string phoneNumber, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked)
{

}

Employee emp1(111, "Steve", "77 N 3484 E", "1234556785", 10.00, 45.00);
Employee emp2(222, "Suresh", "239 N 5103 E", "8835556788", 12.50, 30.00);

int Employee::getEmployeeNumber()
{
    return employeeNumber;
}

void Employee::setEmployeeNumber(int empNum)
{
    employeeNumber = empNum;
}

string Employee::getEmployeeName()
{
    return employeeName;
}

void Employee::setEmployeeName(string empName)
{
    employeeName = empName;
}


string Employee::getStreetAddress()
{
    return streetAddress;
}

void Employee::setStreetAddress(string strtAddrs)
{
    streetAddress = strtAddrs;
}

string Employee::getPhoneNumber()
{
    return phoneNumber;
}

void Employee::setPhoneNumber(string phnNum)
{
    phoneNumber = phnNum;
}

double Employee::getHourlyWage()
{
    return hourlyWage;
}

void Employee::setHourlyWage(double hrWage)
{
    hourlyWage = hrWage;
}

double Employee::getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}

void Employee::setHoursWorked(double hrWorked)
{
    hoursWorked = hrWorked;
}



void printCheck(Employee ee)
{
    cout << "\n\n--------------------- Fluff Shuffle Electronics -------------------------------- \n";
    cout << " Pay to the order of " << ee.getEmployeeName() << "..........................." << ee.calcPay();
    cout << "\n\n United Bank of Eastern Orem \n";
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n";
    cout << " Hours Worked: " << ee.getHoursWorked();
    cout << "\n Hourly Wage: " << ee.getHourlyWage();
}//End of function

 //Main function
int main(Employee ee)
{

    //Calls function to displays information
    printCheck(emp1);
    cout << "\n Press any key to continue..........";
    //getch();
    printCheck(emp2);
    cin.get();
}//End of main
```

Expected output:
[image: This is what it should be outputting]

Current output:
[image: And this is what it is ouputting]

Comment: If you "have no idea what you are doing", talk to your teacher, not us.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead copy-paste the text, as text, and put it into the question body. Please edit your question to do that. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You did not implement `Employee::Employee(int empNum, string empName, string streetAddress, string phoneNumber, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked)` at all.

Comment: You should also learn how to use a *debugger*. With it you can easily step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. That way you should be able to easily see what the problem might be.

Comment: `int main(Employee ee)` -- I'm *pretty sure* this is not a standard-compliant prototype for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

### You are not setting the values of your `Employee` constructor.

Right now it is empty, so when you instantiate an Employee it will have no attribute member values assigned.
**You should do something like this:**

```
Employee::Employee(int empNum, string empName, string streetAddress, string phoneNumber, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked)
{
    
    employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    employeeName = empName;
    this->streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this->phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

}
```

### Your `main()` function is also not standard.

`main()` is the starting point of your program and you shouldn't pass an `Employee` parameter there.

Try something like this:

```
int main()  // Remove Employee argument
{
    // Instantiate your employees here first, then call their functions.
    Employee emp1(1, "John Doe", "10 Downing Street", "555-555-555", 20, 40);
    Employee emp2(2, "Jane Williams", "10 Clark Street", "432-543-222", 20, 40);  
    //Calls function to displays information
    printCheck(emp1);
    cout << "\n Press any key to continue..........";
    //getch();
    printCheck(emp2);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: As this is clearly a homework question and to OP asked for a point in the right direction I think a simple, "You haven't implemented the class constructor" would've sufficed.